# Unexpected behavior of gsub in R

Tags: html, r, regex, pattern-matching

Excuse me for not being more specific in the title, but I don't know how to explain this without an example.

I have a .html file that looks like this:

```html
<TR><TD>log p-value:</TD><TD>-2.797e+02</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>Information Content per bp:</TD><TD>1.736</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>Number of Target Sequences with motif</TD><TD>894.0</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>Percentage of Target Sequences with motif</TD><TD>47.58%</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>Number of Background Sequences with motif</TD><TD>10864.6</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>Percentage of Background Sequences with motif</TD><TD>22.81%</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>Average Position of motif in Targets</TD><TD>402.4 +/- 261.2bp</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>Average Position of motif in Background</TD><TD>400.6 +/- 246.8bp</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>Strand Bias (log2 ratio + to - strand density)</TD><TD>-0.0</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>Multiplicity (# of sites on avg that occur together)</TD><TD>1.48</TD></TR>
```

I read it in:

```
html = readLines("file.html")
```

I am interested in whatever is between `</TD><TD>` and `</TD></TR>`. When I run the following, I get the result I want:

```
mypattern = '<TR><TD>log p-value:</TD><TD>([^<]*)</TD></TR>'
gsub(mypattern,'\\1',grep(mypattern,html,value=TRUE))
[1] "-2.797e+02"
```

It works well for almost all lines I want to match, but when I do the same thing for the last two lines, it does not extract anything.

```
mypattern = '<TR><TD>Strand Bias (log2 ratio + to - strand density)</TD><TD>([^<]*)</TD></TR>'
gsub(mypattern,'\\1',grep(mypattern,html,value=TRUE))
character(0)

mypattern = '<TR><TD>Multiplicity (# of sites on avg that occur together)</TD><TD>([^<]*)</TD></TR>'
gsub(mypattern,'\\1',grep(mypattern,html,value=TRUE))
character(0)
```

Why is this happening? 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If your data structure is really like this. You have a xml file with keys and values so I assume it is easier to utilize this!

```
library(xml2)
xd <- read_xml("file.html", as_html = TRUE)
key_values <- xml_text(xml_find_all(xd, "//td"))
is_key <- as.logical(seq_along(key_values) %% 2)
setNames(key_values[!is_key], key_values[is_key])
```

Comment: Neat library, I'll try it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First, I'll say that I would actually solve this problem like this:

```r
gsub(".+>([^<]+)</TD></TR>", "\\1", html)
#>  [1] "-2.797e+02"        "1.736"             "894.0"            
#>  [4] "47.58%"            "10864.6"           "22.81%"           
#>  [7] "402.4 +/- 261.2bp" "400.6 +/- 246.8bp" "-0.0"             
#> [10] "1.48"
```

But, to answer the question of why your way didn't work, we need to checkout the help file for R regular expressions (`help("regex")`):

> Any metacharacter with special meaning may be quoted by preceding it with a backslash. The metacharacters in extended regular expressions are . \ | ( ) [ { ^ $ * + ? ...

The patterns that you had trouble with included parentheses, which you needed to escape (note the double backslash, since backslashes themselves need to be escaped):

```r
mypattern = '<TR><TD>Multiplicity \\(# of sites on avg that occur together\\)</TD><TD>([^<]*)</TD></TR>'
gsub(mypattern,'\\1',grep(mypattern,html,value=TRUE))
# [1] "1.48"
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the shorter command, it is more useful indeed.